# How to make TListView display order the same as the items were added?

Tags: c++builder, vcl, tlistview, tlistbox

I am adding a list of comet names and numbers into the VCL `TListView` and `TListBox` in C++Builder. I need the display order to be the order in which the names were added. This happens with the `TListBox` but not the `TListView`.

I am loading a `.CSV` file into a `TStringList` and then looping through the `TStringList` to load the contents into the `TListBox` and `TListView`. The `TListBox` displays the names in the order they are added. The `TListView` displays the names and numbers in two columns in an order I can't understand. With the `TListView`, I tried using the function `Add()` and `Insert()`.

Below is my code. The picture shows the different results I get. How can I make the `TListView` display the names and numbers in the order they are added the same as the `TListBox`?

```
TListItem *ListItem;

std::auto_ptr<TStringList> MyCSVFile(new TStringList);
MyCSVFile->Delimiter = ',';
MyCSVFile->StrictDelimiter = true;
MyCSVFile->CommaText = "";
MyCSVFile->Clear();

MyCSVFile->LoadFromFile(GetFileName);
    

for(Row_Num=1; Row_Num < MyCSVFile->Count; Row_Num++){

    Row_string = MyCSVFile->Strings[Row_Num];
    Row_tokens->CommaText = Row_string;

    Name_string = Row_tokens->Strings[Name_Cell_Num]; 
    Num_string = Row_tokens->Strings[Num_Cell_Num]; 

    ListBox1->Items->Add(Name_string); 

    //ListView - Add()
    ListItem = ListView->Items->Add();
    ListItem->Caption = Cell_string;
    ListItem->SubItems->Add( Num_string );

    //Alternate method ListView - Insert()
    //ListItem = ListView->Items->Insert(0);
    //ListItem->Caption = Cell_string;
    //ListItem->SubItems->Insert(0, Num_string);
}
```

[ListBox and ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxJXf.png)

I have tried using the `Add()` and `Insert()` functions with `TListView` but the display order is not the order items are added. I don't know any other way to get items into the `TListView`.